# How would I go about hiding my country for HTTP browsing?

Tags: vpn, proxy, download, http, ip-address

There's a filesharing site I used to use a lot which started blocking US IP addresses. I'm wondering what the best way is of continuing to download from there. I've explored a number of options. First, I started just using HTTP proxies, but they were so slow and 90% of the time I either wouldn't get to the point where I could download it, or it would fail in the middle of the download. I recently started trying to use Tor, and specifying the country by editing the configuration file, but I'm running into another strange problem where it virtually never works. I'm not here to ask for a solution for that problem though. Basically all I want to know is your recommendation for an easy way to download a file from this place without it giving me a heart attack. One other solution I heard about had to do with editing HTTP headers, is that likely to work? Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Ask a friend from another country to download it for you, perhaps? Rent a VPS from another country and use it to proxy? etc..

Comment: may : you can test vpn with no encryption that  has more speed.

Comment: is remote to another server ,possible for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are generally 2 ways to do this -

1. Set up a VPN and use that.  (There are quite a few providers, and you can probably
   get one for about US$5 per month).
2. Use a proxy server in the country you want to appear from.
   2a. If you have a friend overseas, you may be able to set up a "SOCKS" proxy just using 
   SSH to their machine.  This is a minimal roll-your-own proxy
   solution - but a VPN or external proxy is typically easier if you have a few bob
   to spare, unless you enjoy playing with SSH.

Editing HTTP headers will only work in a very few cases - the header you would need to add is an X-FORWARDED-FOR header in each HTTP request, however this information is considered unreliable - because it can be added so easily faked.  Doing a "good job" of faking your location requires modifying the IP address making the connection - which is what the 2 methods above provide.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that thunking the HTTP headers will work.  If the server is blocking IP addresses, it's almost certainly doing it at a lower level (as in `ipchain`).

The easiest way is to have someone from outside the US download it for you.

If you have SSH access to a server outside the US you could use `wget` to download the file and then `SCP` it from the server.  You wanna make sure that what you're doing doesn't go against the terms of use that you would have agreed to.